# Как присвоить class определенному элементу списка?

Tags: javascript

Доброе время суток!
Помогите пожалуйста решить задачу.
Есть простой список из n-го количества элементов

```html
<ul>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
</ul>
```

Еще есть точно такое  же количество элементов кнопок

```html
<div class="owl-dots">
    <button role="button" class="owl-dot"></button>
    <button role="button" class="owl-dot"></button>
    <button role="button" class="owl-dot active"></button>
    <button role="button" class="owl-dot"></button>
</div>
```

Кнопки принадлежат к плагину Owl Carousel и текущий элемент выделяется классом "active".

Суть задачи в следующем, необходимо присваивать class active или current нужному элементу списка в зависимости от того, какой button на текущей момент имеет class active.

Думаю связать элементы списка и кнопки data-атрибутами, например должно получится примерно так:

```html
<ul>
    <li data-item="1"></li>
    <li data-item="2"></li>
    <li data-item="3" class="current"></li>
    <li data-item="4"></li>
</ul>

<div class="owl-dots">
    <button data-item="1" role="button" class="owl-dot"></button>
    <button data-item="2" role="button" class="owl-dot"></button>
    <button data-item="3" role="button" class="owl-dot active"></button>
    <button data-item="4" role="button" class="owl-dot"></button>
</div>
```

Помогите пожалуйста написать скрипт, который будет находить button с классом active и присваивать класс active или current нужному элементу списка

Comment: Если у нас одинаковое количество элементов списка и одинаковое количество кнопок, почему бы не использовать индекс нужного элемента для определения активного ?

Comment: Это нужно делать по нажатию на кнопку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Попробуйте это:**

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $("button.owl-dot").on("click", function() {
      $(this)
        .addClass("active")
        .siblings()
        .removeClass("active")
        .closest("div.test")
        .find("ul.list li")
        .removeClass("current")
        .eq($(this).index())
        .addClass("current");
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.current {
  background-color: red;
}
.active {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test">

  <ul class="list">
    <li class="current">list 1</li>
    <li>list 2</li>
    <li>list 3</li>
    <li>list 4</li>
  </ul>

  <div class="owl-dots">
    <button class="owl-dot active">1</button>
    <button class="owl-dot">2</button>
    <button class="owl-dot">3</button>
    <button class="owl-dot">4</button>
  </div>

</div>
```